# more than one operator "[]" matches these operands

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a class that has both implicit conversion operator() to intrinsic types and the ability to access by a string index operator[] that is used for a settings store.  It compiles and works very well in unit tests on gcc 6.3 & MSVC however the class causes some ambiguity warnings on intellisense and clang which is not acceptable for use.

Super slimmed down version:
https://onlinegdb.com/rJ-q7svG8

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>


struct Setting
{
    int data; // this in reality is a Variant of intrinsic types + std::string
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Setting>> children;
    template<typename T>
    operator T()
    {
        return data;
    }
    template<typename T>
    Setting & operator=(T val)
    {
        data = val;
        return *this;
    }
    Setting & operator[](const std::string key)
    {
        if(children.count(key))
            return *(children[key]);
        else
        {
            children[key] = std::shared_ptr<Setting>(new Setting());
            return *(children[key]);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
    Setting data;
    data["TestNode"] = 4;
    data["TestNode"]["SubValue"] = 55;
    int x = data["TestNode"];
    int y = data["TestNode"]["SubValue"];
    std::cout << x <<std::endl;
    std::cout << y;
    
output:
4
55
```

Error message is as follows:

> more than one operator "[]" matches these operands:
>
> built-in operator "integer[pointer-to-object]" function
>
> "Setting::operator[](std::string key)"
>
> operand types are: Setting [ const char [15] ]

I understand why the error/warning exists as it's from the ability to reverse the indexer on an array with the array itself (which by itself is extremely bizarre syntax but makes logical sense with pointer arithmetic).

```cpp
char* a = "asdf";
char b = a[5];
char c = 5[a];
b == c
```

I am not sure how to avoid the error message it's presenting while keeping with what I want to accomplish. (implicit assignment & index by string)

Is that possible?

Note: I cannot use C++ features above 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the user-defined implicit conversion function template.

```
template<typename T>
operator T()
{
    return data;
}
```

When the compiler considers the expression `data["TestNode"]`, some implicit conversions need to take place. The compiler has two options:

- Convert the `const char [9]` to a `const std::string` and call `Setting &Setting::operator[](const std::string)`
- Convert the `Setting` to an `int` and call `const char *operator[](int, const char *)`

Both options involve an implicit conversion so the compiler can't decide which one is better. The compiler says that the call is ambiguous.

There a few ways to get around this.

#### Option 1

Eliminate the implicit conversion from `const char [9]` to `std::string`. You can do this by making `Setting::operator[]` a template that accepts a reference to an array of characters (a reference to a string literal).

```
template <size_t Size>
Setting &operator[](const char (&key)[Size]);
```

#### Option 2

Eliminate the implicit conversion from `Setting` to `int`. You can do this by marking the user-defined conversion as `explicit`.

```
template <typename T>
explicit operator T() const;
```

This will require you to update the calling code to use direct initialization instead of copy initialization.

```
int x{data["TestNode"]};
```

#### Option 3

Eliminate the implicit conversion from `Setting` to `int`. Another way to do this is by removing the user-defined conversion entirely and using a function.

```
template <typename T>
T get() const;
```

Obviously, this will also require you to update the calling code.

```
int x = data["TestNode"].get<int>();
```

#### Some other notes

Some things I noticed about the code is that you didn't mark the user-defined conversion as `const`. If a member function does not modify the object, you should mark it as `const` to be able to use that function on a constant object. So put `const` after the parameter list:

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const {
    return data;
}
```

Another thing I noticed was this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Setting>(new Setting())
```

Here you're mentioning `Setting` twice and doing two memory allocations when you could be doing one. It is preferable for code cleanliness and performance to do this instead:

```
std::make_shared<Setting>()
```

One more thing, I don't know enough about your design to make this decision myself but do you really need to use `std::shared_ptr`? I don't remember the last time I used `std::shared_ptr` as `std::unique_ptr` is much more efficient and seems to be enough in most situations. And really, do you need a pointer at all? Is there any reason for using `std::shared_ptr<Setting>` or `std::unique_ptr<Setting>` over `Setting`? Just something to think about.

Comment: Thank you, option 1 seems to resolve it.  The shared_ptr was because there is some ambiguity on if this system needs to do some form of shallow copy share of subtrees.  But your right, it technically doesn't need pointers.